# how to drag item from gridview and drop it to listview like gallery android

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, drag-and-drop

i want to drag item from gridview to drop it on listview listview and get the dropped on item position like this picture show[image]

Comment: Higher versions of android support draggable object. But  for device like gingerbread you have to code touch events manually .

Comment: try this draggable lib it may be help you. https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

Comment: please Another solution , this not help me

Comment: Have you find the solution of it, I am trying to do same thing but looking impossible ?